# Integrate groups from external storage into Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi

I'm in the process of updating our Keycloak to version 22. We have a database that contains users and RBAC roles these users may have.

The users are integrated by a custom `UserStorageProvider`, and that works just fine.

However, the old integration we had also started a scheduled task that synchronizes the groups in Keycloak with those in our database by creating or removing Keycloak groups.

This seems very hacky to me, beside being wasteful (this process is executed over and over even though the data rarely changes).

I already found [GroupProviderFactory](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/GroupProviderFactory.html) and [GroupProvider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/GroupProvider.html). Shouldn't it be possible to reimplement those the same way as the `UserStorageProvider`?

To try it I have created a dummy implementation of `GroupProviderFactory` and `GroupProvider`. `getId()` of the former returns `mygroupprovider` and I have run `kc.sh build --spi-group-provider=mygroupprovider`.

However, that didn't work. `getId()` does get called, but not `create`. I couldn't find any documentation or examples, so I don't know if this just isn't possible in general, or if I'm doing something wrong.

So, can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. My error was that I tried to enable the SPI in the `build` command, but not `start`, and you have to do it the other way round.

So, to explain everything I did:

1. Created an implementation of `org.keycloak.models.GroupProvider`, let's call it `MyGroupProvider`.
2. Created an implementation of `org.keycloak.models.GroupProviderFactory` as `GroupProviderFactory<MyGroupProvider>`, let's call it `MyGroupProviderFactory`. The override for `getId()` has to return something unique, say `"mygroupproviderid"`
3. In `resources/META-INF/services` added a file `org.keycloak.models.GroupProviderFactory` with the path of `MyGroupProviderFactory`
4. Created and copied a jar into `/opt/keycloak/providers/` as usual
5. Executed `kc.sh start` with parameters `--spi-group-provider=mygroupproviderid --spi-group-provider-mygroupproviderid-enabled=true`

And that's t.